Why is indexOfFirst() by reference equality slower than indexOf() by classes wrapping the value?
I found collections of items overriding equals() working slowly on indexOf() than ones not by almost 10 times.
my code measured it:
fun main() {
    val list1 = List(65536, Int::toString)
    val list2 = List(65536) { Wrapper(it.toString()) }
    val list3 = List(65536) { Data(it.toString()) }


    for (i in 0..<8) {
        case1(list1, list2, list3)
    }
}

fun case1(list1: List<String>, list2: List<Wrapper>, list3: List<Data>) {

    val string = measureTimeMillis {
        list1.map(list1::indexOf)
    }

    val wrapper = measureTimeMillis {
        list2.map(list2::indexOf)
    }

    val dataClass = measureTimeMillis {
        list3.map(list3::indexOf)
    }


    println(
        "string: ${string.toString().padStart(5, ' ')}, " +
        "wrapper: ${wrapper.toString().padStart(5, ' ')}, " +
        "dataClass: ${dataClass.toString().padStart(5, ' ')}, "
    )
}

class Wrapper(val data: String)
data class Data(val data: String)

and result is:
string: 15492, wrapper: 11214, dataClass: 31157, 
string: 14801, wrapper:  1497, dataClass: 18947, 
string: 16329, wrapper:  1448, dataClass: 19118, 
string: 16086, wrapper:  1439, dataClass: 19026, 
string: 16440, wrapper:  1450, dataClass: 18615, 
string: 16219, wrapper:  1446, dataClass: 19498, 
string: 16397, wrapper:  1474, dataClass: 18292, 
string: 16998, wrapper:  1589, dataClass: 20106, 

So, I searched for a way to do indexOf() with reference equality, and I found this(stackoverflow), and expected it to be faster.
(My project does not need value equality, so I decided to)
val string = measureTimeMillis {
    list1.forEach { x -> list1.indexOfFirst { it === x } }
}

val wrapper = measureTimeMillis {
    list2.forEach { x -> list2.indexOfFirst { it === x } }
}

val dataClass = measureTimeMillis {
    list3.forEach { x -> list3.indexOfFirst { it === x } }
}

but result:
string: 15082, wrapper: 19327, dataClass: 19708, 
string: 14936, wrapper:  7088, dataClass:  7904, 
string: 15964, wrapper:  6829, dataClass:  7564, 
string: 15684, wrapper:  7210, dataClass:  7120, 
string: 16802, wrapper:  7112, dataClass:  8122, 
string: 16743, wrapper:  8641, dataClass:  8761, 
string: 15756, wrapper:  7122, dataClass:  8038, 
string: 16245, wrapper:  7951, dataClass:  7671, 

Speed of using data class was increased by twice, that of using wrapper class dropped a lot, and that of string did not improv virtually.
And, the improved speed was about x5 slower than that of wrapper class at the first case.

Why is comparing by reference equalities slower than one by wrapper classes?

Why was the speed of String not improved at all, while that of data class was improved by twice?

Why are the first lines of results far from the others?


Thank you so much!

Please redo your tests using proper benchmarking tool like JMH. I see you already did multiple iterations and we even see results of JIT, but please be aware that for example you didn't use results of indexOf, so technically speaking, JVM may entirely remove your whole loop. BTW, I observe much different results on my machine, which also suggests the problem is with the benchmark.

Also, I suspect indexOfFirst may be a little slower than indexOf, because it is implemented in Kotlin / JVM bytecode, while indexOf is a part of the Java stdlib and could be potentially more optimized inside the JVM.

Regarding @broot's last comment, you should at least re-run your first test with indexOfFirst { it == x } (comparing for equality and not reference, but still using the same search function).

@broot
Benchmark: State.Benchmark, Mode.AverageTime, Unit: ms/op.
2 forks, and 5 warm-up iter & 10 iter each.
(form: data class, string, wrapper)


indexOfFirst { x -> it === x }
1896.945, 1355.605, 2208.230


list.indexOfFirst() { x -> it == x }
4860.418, 3875.181, 2127.213


list::indexOf
5055.319, 4313.383, 470.460
(wrapper showed ms/opG )


What I found is:

IndexOfFirst is much slower than indexOf.
Reference equality is much better than using equals().
I expected indexOfFirst equals to be slower  than indexOf for classes overriding equals, but it isn't.

